# How to use promise object value in global object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

As shown below, there is a function that pulls data from a specific server using a function that uses a promise object called axios.

```
const getData = async () => {
try {
    const result = await axios.get(
        "https://b2ef45f8-e166-41d7-bd35-9ad159028fbf.mock.pstmn.io/test"
    );

    const products = result.data.products;

    console.log(products);

    console.log(`status:(${result.status}) sucess to connection`);

    const data = JSON.stringify(products);

    return data;
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    console.log("failed to get result.");

    return err;
}
```

};

console.log(getData());

it is free to use the value inside the function, When I try to get the value by calling that function in global space, the value Promise { } is first printed to the console, followed by the contents of the function above. I understands that this is because promises are asynchronous. However, I have to use this promise value (data variable) in the global context, so I want to know how to use it in the global context.

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do. Embrace the fact that all synchronous code will finish before the promise resolves. Everything dependent on the promise data needs to be chained with `await` or `then`, simple as that. If it didn't have to be, then JS wouldn't bother you with all the `async`/`await`/`then` hassle.

Comment: `getData().then(console.log, console.error);`. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my question!

Comment: All async functions return a promise.  The caller of `getData()` must use `await` or `.then()` to get the resolved value from the promise that `getData()` returns.